# Android Saving Captured Image As Android Camera Captured

Tags: android, camera, android-cursor, image-capture

I'm trying to open android's own camera application from my application.It is working!But i have a problem when i want to get information like,

-Image ID

-Image Display Name

-Image Title

-Image Data

-Image Size

-Image Date Taken

which should be stored at MediaStore.I was successful in getting image's path.After that, i have to get information like above but when i try to get information , application throws exception.

Partially My Code is something like this:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        Date date = new Date(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(5)));
        SimpleDateFormat dateF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        SimpleDateFormat timeF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        imageListInfo.add(
                cursor.getString(0) + ";" 
                + cursor.getString(1) + ";" 
                + cursor.getString(2) + ";" 
                + cursor.getString(3) + ";" 
                + cursor.getString(4) + ";"
                + dateF.format(date) + ";"
                + timeF.format(date)
                );
    }
```

There had been no problem before i captured and saved the photo which from default camera application called from my application.

I think there is one problem that should be solved.It is how can i save the image with its information like capturing the photo without calling from my application?

EDIT:

*It is happening when getting id "cursor.getString(0)" code*

```
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: 
cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:139)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
at com.canberk.data.warehouse.BaseActivity.indexingForImageMediaStore(BaseActivity.java:313)
at com.canberk.data.warehouse.BaseActivity$BackGroundWorker.doInBackground(BaseActivity.java:109)
at com.canberk.data.warehouse.BaseActivity$BackGroundWorker.doInBackground(BaseActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your exception. If you do not understand the stack trace, add it to your question via the "edit" link. Also note that there is no requirement for the default camera app on any given device to put the resulting image in `MediaStore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stack trace seems self-explantory: you are accessing a closed `Cursor` from `indexingForImageMediaStore()`.

Comment: what is the meaning of cursor is closed ? is it i have to use uri of internal content instead of external content?But i can find with external content uri unless i capture new photos from my applicaiton :)

Comment: @COvayurt: "what is the meaning of cursor is closed ?" -- it means that you called `close()` on it.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i fix it?Because it can't be wrong.It works normally when i won't capture a photo.I have looked at mediastore database and found captured photo.There some missing elements like , "size" "datetaken" "width" "height"...the photos' elements i captured with default camera applicaiton without calling from my app haven't got missing elements.

Comment: @COvayurt: "Could you please tell me how can i fix it?" -- not really. Find where you are closing it and ensure that you are closing it only when you want to. "Because it can't be wrong" -- obviously, the operating system disagrees with you.

Comment: Ok.I understood the problem.The code is not wrong.It's just Android OS doesn't trace the last added pictures.I have started scanning media manually.Then return my app.It had been fixed :) i think i have to trigger the media scanning with code.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> But i have a problem when i want to get information like ... which should be stored at MediaStore

Well, that data is only in `MediaStore` when the Camera application is being invoked directly by the user to take a photo.  When the application is invoked by an `Intent` to return a photo to your application, the image data may be saved at a location you request, but nothing is implicitly stored in `MediaStore`.

A common technique if your app is requesting the photo, is to do the insert into `MediaStore` first with all the initial metadata you want to associate, which will return the `Uri` you can pass to the Camera app for storing the captured image.  Then after returning back, if you need to enter additional metadata like image size you can read this information and update the database.

Comment: I can save photo where i want to, but there is problem about reviewing the recent captured photo.If i didn't capture photo with my application this exception wouldn't appear.